# How can we set number of branches of decision tree classifier in scikit learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm using scikit-learn but do not know how to set the number of branches for decision trees...
Is the binary tree optimal for the decision trees?

Comment: Check https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think scikit-learn only supports binary trees. According to section 1.10.6 of the trees section of their documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) the only supported tree algorithms are ID3, C4.5, C5.0, and CART. They all output binary trees.